# MySQL stopped working in Xampp on Windows

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

MySql isn't working on xampp. See screenshots

[image]

[image]

I've tried the following ways:

- I've deleted file "ib_logfile1" from e://xampp/mysql/data but didn't work 
  Xampp was unable to uninstall, not event from the installed directory
- I've reinstalled xampp on d drive, It works good on first run. when i close the xampp and run again it again causing problem.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Oh you shouldn't have done that - ib_logfile1 is where all your data is! It's not a really log, it's basically where innodb stores all the data. If you still have a copy of it, restore it and retry from there. Whatever problem you had wasn't due to this file (unless it's corrupted, but I don't think that would make mysql segfault).

Comment: I've restored that file but still same issue.